# Watch in znodes while creating a child znode

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I have created a znode as follows

```
create /test test
```

And also set a watch on that node

```
get /test true
```

If i created a child node for test as

```
create /test/sample sample
```

whether a notification will be sent to the client who set watch in the znode "test".

What my doubt is If a client set watch for a znode and if we create a child to that znode whether notification will be sent to that client

Answer (score 0):

Yes ..
"EventType.NodeChildrenChanged" will be fired to the client

Comment: can u tell me the command so that I can check it manually...@Sandeep Das

Comment: You can use zookeeper GUI (ZooInspector)....Will prevent u from remembering commands ;)

Comment: thank u..but i want to know the command...can u tell me plz @Sandeep Das